# Altair report in HTML but charts only show partially

Tags: javascript, python, html, altair, vega-lite

I built reports with Altair, which include multiple charts(100+), and render them into one HTML file. I send the HTML reports to team members but some of them say they can only see some of the charts displayed. Since I made the charts interactive, you can still see data when hover over the charts.

I can see all the charts on my browser with no problem but I don't know what's the setup to make that available to everyone. I have my team member try to do the same thing to install Altair packages and `selenium` webdriver for Chrome, also turn off adblocker, but still not work out. Does anyone know how to solve this? Or if any other workaround like generate PDF for reporting purpose? Would like to know what setups will be needed if share Altair reports with others in HTML format. Thanks ahead!

Referenced the display troubleshooting here:
https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html

Comment: This might be pretty hard to troubleshoot. I would suggest having your team member try with smaller Altair HTML files to make sure that they can see those charts completely. Then you can try with different browsers and files of different sizes both in your and their computer to find out if this somehow relates to one of those variables. It sounds like a problem that is specific to their machine if everything works well for you.

Comment: Thank you @joelostblom! Yes, I think this would be the solution for it by reducing the size of HTML files. <1MB each file looks working. I also tried to generate the PNG/SVG and print PDF but that way will lose the interactive feature, which is quite useful for us. Wonder if any packages you'd recommend for report building?

Comment: I usually export notebooks as HTML or build a dashboard, but I haven't run into a situation where I create as many graphs as you have mentioned here so I haven't run into any of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer this question without more information, but I suspect this is due to one of two things:

1. viewing the document in an incompatible browser: Vega-Lite requires and ES6 capable browser, so, for example, charts will not show correctly in Internet Explorer and some other browsers; see [Display Troubleshooting](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#general-trouble-shooting) for more information.
2. data that is not visible to the colleague's computer: for example, if you use the json data transformer, then the data source is located on your own computer's filesystem and so charts will fail to render on your colleague's computer.